# Is it safe to add a new website binding on production server on IIS 7.5?

Tags: windows, iis-7.5, web-hosting

We have an existing website hosted in IIS, with multiple bindings in place.

Is it 100% safe to add a new binding on this production environment without the risk of interrupting active sessions or requiring an IIS restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked it myself: Adding a binding does not require a restart and does not end any active sessions.